# 1-week time lag in cross-lagged panel analysis

Tags: modeling, panel-data, lags

I am new to using cross-lagged panel analysis and was planning to use a 3-wave model to assess attitudes about social support, perceived social support, and depression.  I have a 1 week lag between time 1 and 2 and a 3 week time lag between wave 2 and 3.  I was thinking that the 1 week lag (although shorter than what I have seen in other cross-lagged papers) would be appropriate as my research question really is focused on defining the directionality of the variables in my model, and so I thought a 1-week time lag would allow for the variables to be particularly stable, and thus would allow for more straightforward conclusions of the prediction of the residual variance in the cross-lagged effects.

If others have opinions on this I would greatly appreciate it. Also, if anyone has articles, chapters, or any resources on this matter, I would greatly appreciate it!